# Hover for parent element and all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="children">Child 1</div>
    <div class="children">Child 2</div>
    <div class="children">Child 3</div>
    <div class="children">Child 4</div>
</div>
```

In jQuery, I want it so that when you hover over anywhere on "parent" (including "children"), "parent" gets a white border around it. Here is what I currently have:

```
$("div#parent").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("border-color", "white");
});
$("div#parent").mouseOut(function(){
    $(this).css("border-color", "black");
});
```

The problem with this code is that if you mouseout over the child, it often does not become black again. Also, because of the children, it sometimes seems not to fire the hover.

I would like this to work very cleanly and simply without error. What can be done?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: `.hover` already includes both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I use those? Could you give me a code example?

Comment: `$("div").hover(function(){ /*mouse in*/ }, function(){ /*mouse out*/ });` Also, the `mouseOut` method is not defined. I believe you mean `mouseout`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) registers both [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) handlers, so you can pass two event handler functions to `.hover()` first one for `mouseenter` and second for `mouseleave` and remove the [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) handler

```
$("#parent").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("border-color", "white");
},function(){
    $(this).css("border-color", "black");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gsqrX/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nzn7/)

```
$("#parent").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("border-color", "white");
});

$("#parent").on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).css("border-color", "black");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#parent').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("border-color", "white");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("border-color", "black");
    });
});
```